# C - container_of macro

Tags: c

Hi why container_of macro looks like this:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
                const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); \
                (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Is there any risk to use it just as posted below:

```
#define new_container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
                (type *)( (char *)ptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Since we are casting at the end ptr to char*, why we are doing first macro line at all?

Comment: At the very least make sure you put `ptr` in parens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the popular explanation, the

```
const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);
```

line is there for extra safety: the additional initialization ensures that the type of `ptr` is compatible with the type of `member`.

Without that check one could implement it as

```
#define new_container_of(ptr, type, member) \
   (type *)( (char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member) )
```

i.e. without using non-standard extensions like those `({ ... })` statement expressions.

Comment: Yes parens is my mistake, AndreyT's comment seems legit, I didn't think about is, thanks a lot!